# Trigger jQuery events with React component in jasmine tests without jest

Tags: jquery, click, reactjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm having some issues regarding a test where I try to test if the correct event listeners are added. I've read up on the relevant documentation and other SO questions, but can't seem to figure this one out.

In the included code, I've tried to trigger the `click` event in 3 different ways, with no success. I'm using Karma as a spec runner with karma-jasmine, browserify with reactify and testing in Chrome.

My spec loooks like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');

describe('FORM', function() {

  var FORM;

  describe('_addFormListeners(..)', function() {

    var _form;

    var dummy = jasmine.createSpy('dummy');
    var _form_dom_node;

    beforeEach(function(done){

      FORM = require('../FORM.react.js');

      _form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <FORM />
      );

      _form._addFormListeners(dummy);

      done();

    });

    afterEach(function(){

      _form._removeFormListeners(dummy);

    });

    it('will add click event', function(done) {

      _form.refs.SubmitButton.getDOMNode().click();

      expect(dummy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      done();

    });

    it('will add click event', function(done) {

      _form_dom_node = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(_form,'submit-button');

      _form_dom_node.click();

      expect(dummy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      done();

    });

    it('will add click event', function(done) {

      _form_dom_node = $('.submit-button');

      _form_dom_node.click();

      expect(dummy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      done();

    });

  });

});
```

And my FORM-component look basically like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var _     = require("underscore");
var $     = require("jquery");

module.exports = React.createClass({
  _addFormListeners : function(callback){

    $('[data-rel="submit"]')
      .on( 'click', callback);

    $('form[name="form"]')
      .on( 'submit', callback);

  },
  _removeFormListeners : function(callback){

    $('[data-rel="submit"]')
      .off( 'click', callback);

    $('form[name="form"]')
      .off( 'submit', callback);

  },
  render: function() {


    return (<div>
                    <button ref={'SubmitButton'} type="button" className="submit-button button inline-block primary left-margin" data-rel="submit">
                      Submit
                    </button>
                    </div>);
  }
});
```

If I set the button type to "submit", I get the `Some of your tests did a full page reload!`-error, indicating that, yes, the click event is fired, but the listener is not added.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I made an issue about this, how the virtual event system in React doesn't play nice with jQuery or the normal browser events: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3249

At the end of the day, nobody really cares. The best solution you have that is supposed to be guaranteed to work is using the React Test Utils: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate

Like so:

```
var node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.input);
React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.click(node);
React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.change(node, {target: {value: 'Hello, world'}});
React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(node, {key: "Enter"});
```

...which you're already bringing in TestUtils it seems, so you should change your code accordingly:

```
// won't work:
// _form.refs.SubmitButton.getDOMNode().click()

// will work:
TestUtils.Simulate.click(_form.refs.SubmitButton);
```

Comment: remove the getDOMNode(), since the Simulate module takes React components.

Comment: Changed the code to
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(_form.refs.SubmitButton);

And did not help :/